# SQL - Value in list, but not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If you have a list of names e.g. Ian, Stephen and a database table as follows:

```
Names (table name)
Ian
Stephen
Maria
```

You could find the names in the list that appear in the table by this query: select * from names where names not in ('Ian','Stephen').  This would return 'Maria'.

How would I find values that exist in the list, but not in the database? For example, if I had a list of: Ian,Maria,Kevin and a table of:

```
Names (table name)
Ian
Maria
```

How could I write a query to return Kevin? I know I could load the list into a separate table and LEFT JOIN them, but I wandered if there was an easier way.

Comment: What data source are you getting "Kevin" from? It has to come from somewhere. . .

Comment: @jchapa, it is just a list copied from Excel.

Comment: Do you copy it by hand? Or do you use some tool to create the query from the list?

Comment: Problem is, you cannot compare direct, your remark about the separate table is the solution. Otherwise you could use the scripting language (you're not using) to remove all queried values from the list.

Comment: @Norla, as stated in the question I have tried a different table.

Comment: You've really lost me at "easier way."  Easier for whom?  I hate typing commas and quotation marks over and over, so I might connect to an excel sheet via OPENROWSET.  Or the union/CTE method is good.  Or anything.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name, SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easier way in SQL.  Doing the `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT IN` is the SQL way of doing it, but you need a table.  Now, you don't have to create an actual table.  You can have something like:

```
with names as (
     select 'Ian' as name union all
     select 'Maria' as name union all
     select 'Kevin' as name
)
select *
from names n
where n.name not in (select name from t)
```

You could also do this in Excel:

1. Put the values in a column
2. Create an `in` list and run the query
3. Put the results in a column
4. Use `vlookup` or `match` to find the differences

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the WITH statement.  This is a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name from
(select "Ian" name from dual
 union
 select "Maria" from dual
 union
 select "Stephen" from dual) a
left outer join Names n using (name)
where n.name is null
```

Comment: @Barmer you are fast, by the time I experiment ;) got downvoted for first wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable 
where names in ('kevin', 'maria', 'ian')
```

### UPDATED with correct input

I want to scratch the above :$

Please take a look at the following. And it's **not** the best query though. But I wanted to tried it out anyway.

Reference * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb1a5/1)

Table:

```
NAME
john
ian
robin
maria
fen
```

Query:

```
select x.* from (
select * from names
union all
select 'kevin'
union all 
select 'ian'
union all
select 'maria') as x
where x.name not in 
(select * from names)
;
```

Results:

```
NAME
kevin
```

Comment: @W0051977 Do take a look at the SQLFIDDLE sample.

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL I would load the list of names into a table variable and join it to your Names table for either version of the search.  Since variable tables reside in memory, this avoids the overhead of creating a normal table or temp table and writing the values to disk for a one time operation.

```
Declare @Temp table
(
    Name varchar(32)
)

Insert Into @Temp
Select 'Ian'
Union
Select'Stephen'
Union 
Select'Kevin'


Select
    T.Name
From @Temp as T
    left join Names as N
        on T.Name = N.Name
Where N.Name IS NULL
```

In my experience this join structure is much more efficient than the "NOT IN" method.

EDIT: Updated code block for DB version

Comment: the NOT IN statement would not work.  Please see bonCodigo's answer.  That would return no rows.  I want the query to return 'Kevin'.

Comment: @w0051977 the NOT IN syntax does work if you load your list into a variable table, you just flip the relationship from what you had in your example.  In every case I can remember though, a variable table and join out performed IN  or NOT IN logic for anything more than a handful of values.

Answer (score 0):

Not useful to the OP, but if you are in a SQL Server 2008 or higher environment, this syntax should work as well.

```
SELECT
    List.NAME
FROM ( VALUES
        ('Ian')
        ,('Maria')
        ,('Kevin')
    ) AS List(NAME)
    LEFT JOIN NAMES AS N
        ON List.NAME = N.NAME
WHERE N.NAME IS NULL
```